# Uniqueness of positive square root of postive element in C* algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

> ```
> If a is a positive element then it has a unique positive square root, i.e. a unique b positive such that b^2=a.
> ```

I understand the existence part of the proof. If we define $f(x)=\sqrt x$ then $f\in C(\sigma (a))$ as $\sigma (a)$ non-negative. $b=f(a)$ satisfies $b^2=a$ and $b\ge0$. 
 My advisor gave me another proof for the uniqueness part and I want to understand it, in addition to the "popular" proof in which we use the fact that $f\circ g (a) = f(g(a))$ for $f,g\in C(\sigma (a))$ (continuous functional calculus respects composition). 
 So, consider the special case of a C*-algebra of the form C(X). Positive elements here are continuous functions with nonnegative values. Here we can directly see that there is only one positive square root. 
In general, suppose $c$ is some other positive square root of $a$. We want to show that $c = f(a)$. 
$a$ and $f(a)$  are elements in the C*-subalgebra $C^*(1,c)$, which is commutative. But $C^*(1,c)$ is isomorphic to $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff $X$, so we're back to the previous paragraph.
 
 Now, I understand the proof, but I'm a little bit worried that we "identify" between positive elements in isomorphic $C^*$ algebras. Is it true that *-isomorphism preserves positive elements? do we really need this fact to complete the proof?

Thank you.

Comment: you are asking if you really need the spectral theorem  ?

Comment: and a isomorphism of C*-algebras preserving the norm is of the form $A \to U^* A U$ for some unitary operator $U$, hence preserving the spectrum and positive elements ?

Comment: @user1952009: that is not true.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : what is not true ?

Comment: @user1952009: the only assertion you made: that isomorphisms of C $^*$-algebras are implemented by unitaries.  Not true.

Comment: @MartinArgerami  that was more a question than a assertion... then help me, explain why, give a counter-example....

Comment: I'm not aware of easy examples (not saying that there aren't, but for sure they cannot be finite-dimensional). A source of lots of examples is Sorin Popa's (and several of his former students) work on crossed product II $_1$-factors, where he is able to prescribe the outer automorphism group (i.e., the quotient of the automorphism group by the inner automorphisms). It is also well-known that the hyperfinite II $_1$-factor has non-inner automorphisms. On the non-von Neumann  front, I know that automorphism groups of C $^*$-algebras are complicated, but I have no examples off the top of my head.

Comment: ok so that was not completely dumb as it is not so easy to show it is not true :) tks I'll try to understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Alternative Proof: Calculus*

For positive elements you have:
$$a,b\geq0:\quad a^2=b^2\implies a=\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{b^2}=b$$

exploiting the functional calculus:
$$x^*x=xx^*:\quad g(f(x))=(g\circ f)(x)$$

Concluding uniqueness.

Answer (score 3):

Once you know that positive elements are those of the form $a^*a$, you have 
$$
\pi(a^*a)=\pi(a^*)\pi(a)=\pi(a)^*\pi(a)\geq0. 
$$
This shows that any $*$-homomorphism preserves positivity.

If you restrict to isomorphisms, you can show it directly also if you define "positive" as "selfadjoint and $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\infty)$". Because 
$a-\lambda I$ is invertible if and only if $\pi(a)-\lambda I=\pi(a-\lambda I)$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you!
am I missing something or this argument is really important for the completeness of the proof?